# Proof that $x_n = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{2}{3^2}+\dots+\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$ diverges using Cauchy test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Stopped at this step:
$$ |x_{n+p} - x_n| = |\sum^{n+p}_{k=n+1}\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}| $$
How can I remove the module and get rid of $p$ to find $N(\varepsilon)$? Maybe I should try something like:$$\dfrac{1}{k}-\dfrac{1}{k+1}?$$

Comment: Note that you can remove the absolute value, because the sum is always positive.

Comment: You can't prove something which is wrong. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}$ grows at the same pace as the harmonic series which is divergent.

Comment: Why are you worrying for module whenever $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Yep, this sequence is really diverges. I'll change the title

Comment: Note that $k\gt \frac {k+1}2$ for $k\gt 1$. This is a crude estimate, but should help you if you know how to handle the harmonic series. It is often possible to resort to crude estimates when numerator and denominator are polynomials - ideally you want to cancel all much as possible to simplify. Constant multiples (here $\frac 12$) often make no difference to the convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show it is divergent using Cauchy test then note that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:

$\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}=\frac{k}{k^2+2k+1}\geq\frac{k}{k^2+2k^2+k^2}=\frac{1}{4k}$

And hence: (we don't need absolute value as all the terms in the sum are positive)

$\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{k}{(k+1)^2}\geq\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\frac{1}{4k}\geq\frac{p}{4(n+p)}$

So now let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{8}$. For each $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ we can choose $n=n_0$ and $p=n_0$. They satisfy $|a_{n+p}-a_n|\geq\frac{n_0}{4(n_0+n_0)}=\epsilon$. So the sequence is not Cauchy.

Comment: Can I take as an estimate $\frac{1}{2k}$, not $\frac{1}{4k}$? Does it matter or not?

Comment: Yes, you can. With $\frac{1}{2k}$ the inequality is true for $k\geq 3$, you can check it. So then just don't forget to take $n\geq 3$ in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{(i+1)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(i+1) - 1}{(i+1)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+1)}-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+1)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(i+1)} - const=\infty$$

Hence it diverges.